# Calling local functions in closure by name

Tags: javascript

I have the following code structure:

```
(function() {
   var Module = (function() {
      var firstMethod = function() {
         var name = 'secondMethod';
         console.log(window[name]());
      };
      var secondMethod = function() {
         return 2;
      };
      return {
         firstMethod: firstMethod
      };
   })();
   Module.firstMethod();
})();
```

The code should return `2` but it returns an error that `window[name]` is undefined, which is true.

Why is this undefined, and how can I solve this?

Comment: You declared your `secondMethod` inside a function, so it is not visible to outer scopes. `window` is the global object, which is the outermost scope. Inner functions can see outside their scope, but you can't see inner functions from outside.

Comment: @saadq you should just copy + paste that into an answer since that is basically the **explanation** behind the issue the OP has

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you want to do: you define `var secondMethod`, which makes it local. `window` is for global variables. You could either:

```
window.secondMethod = function() { return 2 }
```

or:

```
(function() {
   function Module() {
      this.firstMethod = function() {
         var name = 'secondMethod';
         console.log(this[name]());
      };
      this.secondMethod = function() {
         return 2;
      };
      return this;
   };
   var module = new Module();
   module.firstMethod();
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(function () {
    var Module = (function () {
        var firstMethod = function () {
            var name = 'secondMethod';
            console.log(window[name]());
        };
        window.secondMethod = function () {
            return 2;
        };
        return {
            firstMethod: firstMethod
        };
    })();
    Module.firstMethod();
})();
```

Comment: @Tivie no, poster added secondMethod to window object.